# Validations for DatePicker control in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I am using DatePicker control from sap.ui.commons library.
I want to add validations to this date. What can be the best possible way to have validations apart from implementing change method ?

Is it possible for the framework to popup the error message in the red color as we get to see in some standard form?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If someone googled for how to validate input in Date(Time)Picker, take a look at this answer: [stackoverflow.com/a/48482544](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482544/5846045).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DatePicker's `valueState` property for that.

In the below example, it shows the control with a red overlay (`sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error`) in case the selected date is longer than a week ago:

```
var oDP = new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker({
    valueState :{
        parts     : ["/myDate"], //bound to a 'myDate' property in your model
        formatter : function(oValue) {
            var oneWeekAgo = new Date();
            oneWeekAgo.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7);
            return (oValue < oneWeekAgo) ? sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error : sap.ui.core.ValueState.None;
        }
    }
});
```

Update: For a full-blown example with a custom error message see this example: http://jsbin.com/nolil/2/edit

Comment: Thanks Qualiture..I had just one query here.... can we omit this parts option if we are not tying with any model????

Comment: I don't think that's possible. It makes no sense either, what's the point of using UI5 controls if you're not using a model? Translated to your case, how would you validate if you don't know what you're validating? For instance, you could have `parts : ["fromDate", "toDate"]` and in your formatter check whether the to-date is after the from-date or not :-) Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh ok fine.... I have tied it to a model... also I had one more query... can we change the text we get to see when the validation of the field fails and ValueState is set to Error. I know in sap.m.Inuput field there is valueStateText property but in case of sap.ui.commons.TextField I could not find that. But when the validation fails... "Invalid Entry" appears...in the tool tip. I was just trying some way to edit it.. bt I am not getting it.