# Validate input of datetime picker

Tags: sapui5

How to register validationError callback for datetimepicker in XML view and how to get this event fired for invalid date input.

The [datetimepicker control](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DateTimePicker.html#constructor) is an input box with a popup date picker.

The user can type directly into the input or use the date picked to select a date. I can add sophisticated validation to the datetime value but I am trying to simply trigger the validationError event when the user types an invalid date into the box, for example "1010101010010101010101010" or "32/15/2019".

Ideally I am looking for a constraint that tests for a valid date value and triggers the validationError() function if needed.

I guess a workaround is to use the change() event and do the validation in JS, set the valueState etc, but I want to understand what the datetimepicker can do in this regard without having to resort to excess JS.

I am convinced this must be in the docs somewhere but have not yet found anything conclusive. I feel strictParsing should play some part.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991147/setting-constraints-to-sap-m-datepicker)about setting date range constraints via declaring a new data type. I thought this might be a solution but I am stuck with how to set the constraint for 'a valid date' input value.

Reading the SAPUI5 docs about [sap.ui.model.type.DateTime](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f3070d6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) it mentions

> The DateTime type supports the following validation constraints:
>
> maximum (expects an dateTime presented in the source-pattern format)
>   minimum (expects an dateTime presented in the source-pattern format)

which gives no pointers over how to do a straight date validity or format check.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT - on suggestion of @Matbtt and reference to docs I altered the type to the string literal `sap.ui.model.type.DateTime`. However the snippet then produced no output. I traced this to the binding to the model where I was binding to a string. When changed to bind to a JS date object this was fixed.

EDIT - on suggestion of @Developer added validationError callback but does not appear to work. See snippet.

```js
// JSON sample data
var classData = {className: "Coding 101", id: 800, startdate: "2017-12-31T23:59:59.000"}

// convert JSON date to JS date object and format via moment for UI5 consumption
classData.startdateraw = new Date(classData.startdate)
classData.startdatefmt = moment(classData.startdateraw).format('YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm-ss') 

sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
   "use strict";
   sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
     onInit: function() {

    // create JSON model instance
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    // set the data for the model
    oModel.setData(classData);
   
    // set model to core.
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

    // Enable validation !!
    sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().registerObject(this.getView(), true);
     
    
     this.getView().byId("startDate").attachValidationError(function(){
        
        alert('Validation error fires - hoorah')
        
      }) 
       
     },
     valError : function(){
       console.log("There was a validation error")
      }
   });
   sap.ui.xmlview({
     viewContent: jQuery("#myView").html()
   }).placeAt("content");
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/1.7.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>

<script id="myView" type="ui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View controllerName="MyController" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form">


    <f:SimpleForm id="EditForm" maxContainerCols="2" editable="true" width="25rem" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" path="{}">
      <f:content>


        <Label id="lblStartDate" text="Start" design="Bold" labelFor="startDate" />
        <DateTimePicker 
            id="startDate" 
            placeholder="Enter a crazy date and time, e.g. 23/01/12345" 
            valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss" 
            validationError="valError"
            value="{
             path: '/startdateraw',
                type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime',  
                strictParsing: 'true'
              }" 
              />


      </f:content>
    </f:SimpleForm>

  </mvc:View>
</script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: For invalid inputs, you need to attach handler to the `parseError` event instead. I added my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482544/5846045) which includes generating UI messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by handling change event of [sap.m.DateTimePicker](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DateTimePicker.html):

```
handleChange : function(oEvent){
   var bValid   = oEvent.getParameter("valid");

   if(!bValid){             
      sap.m.MessageToast.show("Entered date range isn't valid");
      return;
   }
}
```

Jsbin working [example](http://jsbin.com/tosebibudi/1/edit?html,js,output).

EDITED 15:03 310117

Change event of sap.m.DateTimePicker is borrowed [event](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DatePicker.html#event:change) from class sap.m.DatePicker.

Comment: Thanks Jaro - I have noted your solution. Can you provide a link to the docs that describe the valid parameter?

Comment: Here https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DatePicker.html#event:change

Comment: thanks but the part of that page in the API you intend me to see is not obvious. Can you be more specific? Also, I looked at the DateTimeInput-dbg.js source file and can see mention of `valid` in the parameters for the change event. Description says  `if set, the entered value is a valid date. If not set the entered value cannot be converted to a date.` Therefore it seems that your workaround is viable.

Comment: Please forget about DateTimeInput and look at the link I sent in my comment (same as the link in my edited part). It tells from api: {boolean} oControlEvent.getParameters.valid => Indicator for a valid date. You are right that, there is not explicitly written true is valid and false is not valid, but when one tests it, true is for valid case and false is for opposite.

Answer (score 3):

## Resolution

First, we need to distinguish between the events *parse error* and *validation error.*

- [**`parseError`**](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#events/parseError) is fired when the user input could not be parsed (e.g. "123123").
- [**`validationError`**](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#events/validationError) is fired only when the input could be parsed but **violates one of the `constraints`** defined in the [property binding info](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.PropertyBindingInfo) object.

With the help of `type` and `constraints` in property binding, invalid user inputs can be automatically prevented from being stored in the model.

Additionally, you can also register the control or the entire application in the `MessageManager` for automatically generating the error messages in order to notify and guide the user what to do.

Refer to "[Formatting, Parsing, and Validating Data](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8)" and "[Validation Messages](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/a90d93df5a024e8bb18826b699c9aaa7)".

## Sample

Here are some samples with `sap.m.DateTimePicker` corresponding to the model:

### `JSONModel`

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/ui/core/Core",
], async (XMLView, JSONModel, core) => {
  "use strict";

  const control = await XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      core:require="{
        TypeDateTime: 'sap/ui/model/type/DateTime'
      }"
      displayBlock="true"
    >
      <App>
        <Page showHeader="false" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
          <ObjectAttribute title="Model value" text="{/myDate}" />
          <ObjectAttribute title="Minimum Date" text="today" />
          <DateTimePicker id="myDTP"
            width="15rem"
            value="{
              path:'/myDate',
              type: 'TypeDateTime',
              formatOptions: {
                style: 'medium/short'
              }
            }"
            parseError="alert('Parse error')"
            validationError="alert('Validation error')"
          />
        </Page>
      </App>
    </mvc:View>`,
    afterInit: function() {
      const dateTimeValueBinding = this.byId("myDTP").getBinding("value");
      dateTimeValueBinding.getType().setConstraints({
        minimum: new Date(), // today
      });
    },
    models: new JSONModel({
      myDate: new Date(),
    }),
  });

  core.getMessageManager().registerObject(control, true);
  control.placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.unified,sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon_dark"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

- API reference: [`sap/ui/model/type/DateTime`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.type.DateTime)

### `ODataModel`

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/odata/v4/ODataModel",
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/ui/core/Core",
], async (XMLView, ODataModel, Controller, core) => {
  "use strict";
  const control = await XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View controllerName="demo.MyController"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      core:require="{
        TypeDateTimeOffset: 'sap/ui/model/odata/type/DateTimeOffset'
      }"
      displayBlock="true"
    >
      <App>
        <Page
          showHeader="false"
          class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding"
          binding="{
            path: '/People(userName=%27sandyosborn%27)/Trips(20)',
            events: {
              dataReceived: '.onDateTimeReceived'
            }
          }"
        >
          <ObjectAttribute
            title="Model value"
            text="&#34;{ path: 'StartsAt', targetType: 'any' }&#34;"
          />
          <ObjectAttribute title="Nullable" text="false" />
          <DateTimePicker id="myDTP"
            busy="true"
            busyIndicatorDelay="1"
            width="15rem"
            value="{
              path: 'StartsAt',
              type: 'TypeDateTimeOffset',
              formatOptions: {
                style: 'medium/short'
              },
              constraints: {
                nullable: false
              }
            }"
            parseError="alert('Parse error')"
            validationError="alert('Validation error')"
          />
        </Page>
      </App>
    </mvc:View>`,
    models: new ODataModel({
      serviceUrl: "https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/(S(o1bizjomxywpc12mu2ad3fje))/",
      autoExpandSelect: true,
      operationMode: "Server",
    }),
    controller: new (Controller.extend("demo.MyController", {
      onDateTimeReceived: function() {
        this.byId("myDTP").setBusy(false);
      },
    }))(),
  });
  core.getMessageManager().registerObject(control, true);
  control.placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.unified,sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon_dark"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "demo": "./" }'
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

- API Reference: [`sap/ui/model/odata/type/DateTimeOffset`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTimeOffset)
- Documentation: "[Dates, Times, Timestamps and Time Zones](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/6c9e61dc157a40c19460660ece8368bc)" (must-read)

#### Note

Unlike `sap/ui/model/type/Date*`, there is **currently no support for `minimum` & `maximum` constraints** in `sap/ui/model/odata/type/*` ***yet*** (Except for `Decimal`).

Until then, you could extend the `DateTimeOffset` type and implement the `validateValue` method accordingly. Sample: [https://embed.plnkr.co/qatUyq](https://embed.plnkr.co/qatUyq?show=model%2Ftype%2FDataTimeOffset.js,view%2FDetail.view.xml,preview&autoCloseSidebar)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the fully qualified object name in your data type declaration as you're referring to a JavaScript object not to a build in HTML type. If you change the following part:

`DateTime` to `sap.ui.model.type.DateTime`

it will work. Please be aware that attributes like `valueFormat` or `displayFormat` as used in your example are ignored if a type is in use. In this case you have to provide these information in the binding. For further details please check the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime.html) of the type implementation.

An shortened example can be found [here](https://jsbin.com/vosivet/edit?html,output). More [examples](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.model.type.DateTime/samples) can be found in the UI5 Explored application which is in general a good starting point. An explanation of binding in general can be found [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/68b9644a253741e8a4b9e4279a35c247.html).

Comment: Thanks Mat. I cannot help but feel baffled by the array of datetime input options and their combination. I think I need to go to 'input school'. Besides the API documentation as per your link, which I find a bit cryptic, is there a single source document or tutorial on inputs and validation? UI5 seems very capable but I am in danger of falling down a knowledge gap. [If you know any SAPUI5 bloggers inputs and their options and effects would be a great topic to write about. Bound dates have the additional issue of how to receive the changed data too.]

Comment: This is indeed a complex topic as types need to handle a lot of different backend systems, e.g. legacy system. I added more links to official resources. I'm not aware of a blogger who wrote about this specific issue. 
Could you clarify the last sentence? What does receive changed data mean?

Comment: Thanks - I am re-reading the binding docs you linked. My last point was regarding a concern of how the data would be fed back into the model.

Comment: The value is automatically set to the model if the value has been validated by the type implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to that much work in JS, I believe you can work with the `validationError` event. Simply set in in your XML, `validationError="functionNameHere"` and in your JS you can just set the ValueState to error. The `validationError` event is fired when the value can't be sent to the model, so you don't have to do any checks on the formatting, this event occurring means the formatting is indeed wrong. You can check the link below to read the documentation.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#event:validationError

Comment: Thanks - edited the snippet to include a validationError callback but this appears not to be called.

Comment: The event `validationError` alone isn't enough as it's only triggered if the value was out of the defined `constraints` range. To check if the entered value was in a proper format in the first place, the [`parseError` needs to be handled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482544/5846045) additionally.