# Mask input for sap.m.Date(Time)Picker

Tags: sapui5

With the `sap.m.DateTimePicker`, it's possible for a user to either select a value from the drop-down list or enter it manually. I'm wondering if there's a way to add a mask to the manual input box that matches the `valueFormat` of the `DateTimePicker`.

I know there's a `sap.m.MaskInput` as well, so maybe there's a way to combine the two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new *private* module named [sap.m.MaskEnabler](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/MaskEnabler.js) which the sap.m.InputBase (i.e. DateTimePicker) is supposed to make use of.

> (MaskEnabler) should be applied to the prototype of a `sap.m.InputBase`.

The mask feature is currently enabled only in [sap.m.TimePicker](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TimePicker/preview) (v1.54). According to [this commit](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/c1a703e397e414db09379480874b331f3d2b74ee) message, however, the same feature will arrive to the Date(Time)Picker as well:

> This change prepares for refactoring of DatePicker and TimePicker so the
>   common code of both pickers can be moved to a new common control that
>   they may extend.

Therefore, if it's not urgent, and depending on your project, I'd not create a new custom control and then throw it away once the mask feature has arrived.

I'll update my answer when it's available.

---

Until then (and even afterwards), you can still **guide** the user to enter the data in the correct format via OData binding type [`sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime/):

```
<DateTimePicker
  value="{
    path: 'myODataModel>myDateTime',
    type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime',
    constraints: {
      isDateOnly: true,
      displayFormat: 'Date'
    }
  }"
  minDate="{...}"
  maxDate="{...}"
/>
```

- [In contrast to `formatter`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/index_v1.html#docs/guide/91f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html#loio91f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070__section_N10078_N10013_N10001), `type` allows us to keep two-way data binding.
- The entered value is automatically intercepted from updating the model data when...

  1. It could not be parsed due to an invalid format ([fires `parseError`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482544/5846045))
  2. It could be parsed but the `constraints` were violated (fires `validationError`)
- If you [enable handling UI messages](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/a90d93df5a024e8bb18826b699c9aaa7)
  additionally, the framework will then take care of creating the appropriate
  message for the user:

  [image: OpenUI5 Input Validation Date]

**Example:** [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482544](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482544/5846045)

Comment: Great! I'll just use a placeholder value for now and will switch to the new feature in the DateTimePicker when it becomes available

Comment: @GianPaoloBuffo You can keep the placeholder but UI5 offers more powerful ways to inform users about how to enter the data correctly. Thanks to the two-way data binding and binding type, the data will be always correctly stored in the model and appropriately formatted in the UI. Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to combine the two sap.m.DateTimePicker and sap.m.MaskInput is to develop your own control . Documentation : https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f1703b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.

Another way is to just use the Placeholder of the DateTimePicker Input field. This does not provide the same functionality as a MaskInput, but helps the user which valueFormat is expected in the input when entering it manually.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a binding in your input box, you could set the type in the binding to eg. sap.ui.model.type.Date. This way you get some automatic formatting when field validation is triggered. There are other types available and you could inherit from sap.ui.model.SimpleType to code your own.

Comment: I then lose the functionality of the `DateTimePicker` though, specifically the drop-down calendar