# Adding custom event "liveChange" to date picker

Tags: sapui5

I have requirement that `sap.m.DatePicker` should prevent alphabets but accept numbers. And the maximum input length should be 10.

When two digits entered for date, e.g. "10", a dot (".") should be automatically added. Also month. At the end, it should look like "10.12.2019" in DatePicker. I guess it would be possible with `liveChange` event, but DatePicker doesn't have `liveChange`.

Please let me know how to add custom `liveChange` event in DatePicker. It would be great help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mask input for sap.m.Date(Time)Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167158/mask-input-for-sap-m-datetimepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Currently (as of SAPUI5 1.64), there is no event such as `liveChange` for `DatePicker`. To add this functionality, you can create your own control and let it extend `DatePicker`. Then add the control to your view, attach an event handler and update the `DatePicker`'s value using [`DatePicker#setValue`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker/methods/setValue).

You can take a look at

- how to create a custom control in SAPUI5 [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/18/how-to-create-a-custom-ui5-control/).
- the `liveChange` implementation of `sap.m.Input` [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/d69f9e66f67bb7cbe3dae9e0a075351114ffd4cb/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Input.js#L1380).

The `maxLength` property of the input will be set by SAPUI5 automatically if you specify the `DatePicker`'s property [`displayFormat`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker/methods/getDisplayFormat), in your case `dd.MM.yyyy`.

Comment: `liveChange` is now supported out of the box: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72816026/5846045

Answer (score 0):

OpenUI5/SAPUI5 1.104 adds the `liveChange` event to the following controls:

- `sap.m.DateTimeField` controls, e.g.:

  - `sap.m.DatePicker`
  - `sap.m.DateTimePicker`
  - `sap.m.DateRangeSelection`
- `sap.m.TimePicker`
- `sap.m.MaskInput`

See [commit: `72fdbf4`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/72fdbf4f8ab01e16801854d8543dc4796e187bb7).